# Trying to move the video feed to the far left of the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video feed that is in the middle of my webpage. I would like to be able to move it to the left.  Having used div in the past and CSS tags  position: absolute; left: 60px; top: 180px; I understand how to move objects.  For some reason, this seems to be different.  How it stays in the middle of the page is my one big curiousity.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="WebRTC code samples">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="WebRTC RPI-WebRTC-Stream Testing Page">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="images/webrtc-icon-192x192.png">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Raspberry WebRTC Stream">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta id="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

  <base target="_blank">

  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/webrtc-icon-192x192.png">
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

</head>
<body>

  <div id="container">
 <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline controls muted width="100%" height="100%"></video>
 <div>
      <button id="Connect">Connect</button>
      <button id="Disconnect">Disconnect</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- <script src="js/lib/adapter.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js/common.js"></script>
  <!-- 
  <script src="js/main_rws_orig.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="js/sdputils.js"></script>
  <script src="js/peerconnection_client.js"></script>
  <script src="js/websocket_signaling.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main_rws.js"></script>
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js">

</body>
</html>
```

css File

```
 /*
     *  Copyright (c) 2015 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
     *
     *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
     *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
     *  tree.
     */
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }

    .highlight {
      background-color: #eee;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      margin: 0 0 30px 0;
      padding: 0.2em 1.5em;
    }
    .warning {
      color: red;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    div#errorMsg p {
      color: #F00;
    }
    }

    a#viewSource {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 1em 0 0 0;
    }

    div#links a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    }
      div#links a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    }

    div.outputSelector {
    margin: -1.3em 0 2em 0;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    /* hack! to detect non-touch devices */
      div#links a {
                    line-height: 0.8em;
      }
    }

    audio {
    max-width: 100%;
    }
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    word-break: break-word;
    }

    button {
    background-color: #d84a38;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0.7em 0.6em 0.7em;
    }

    button:active {
    background-color: #cf402f;
    }

    button:hover {
    background-color: #cf402f;
    }
    button[disabled] {
    color: #ccc;
    }

    button[disabled]:hover {
    background-color: #d84a38;
    }

    canvas {
      background-color: #ccc;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    code {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    }

    div#container {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    max-width:40em; 
    padding: 

    }

    div#links {
            padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    }


    html {
    /* avoid annoying page width change
    when moving from the home page */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    img {
    border: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    }
    input[type=radio] {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    }

    p {
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    }

    p#data {
    border-top: 1px dotted #666;
    font-family: Courier New, monospace;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 1em 0 0 0;
    }

    p.borderBelow {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

    section p:last-of-type {
    margin: 0;
    }
    section:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: none;
      padding: 0 0 1em 0;
    }

    select {
      margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
    }

    h1 span {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    strong {
      font-weight: 500;
    }

    textarea {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    video {
      background: #222;
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
      .highlight {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        padding: 0.2em 1em;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
      button:active {
        background-color: darkRed;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line:
This should do the needful.

```css
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
```

Comment: div#container {
/*  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; */
max-width:40em; 
padding: 
}
It worked !  Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have this in your css and your video is within the div#container. In css, margin: 0 auto often centers the element. You could remove either the margin or max-width and it should move to the left.

```
div#container {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    max-width: 40em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  max-width:40em; is needed, or the stream takes up the entire page,   Removing imargin: 0 auto 0 auto;  worked